# Riding on a narrowboat in London

Tags: uk, london, riverboats

I think it would be interesting to ride on a [narrowboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrowboat) for maybe an hour or two. Unfortunately, I do not know how one would go about arranging this. Ideally I'd like to be able to leave from London and maybe catch a train back or something.

Any ideas? If possible how much would it likely cost? And what sorts of amenities could I expect? Is it reasonable to expect restrooms on board, for example?

Comment: An hour or two won't  get you far - you could explore some of the canals, at best. They tend to go very slowly.  Would a tour be ok?

Comment: Sure - that would be interesting. How long would a tour likely last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the more famous tours is run by the Canal Museum:

[Summer Canal Boat Tours](http://www.canalmuseum.org.uk/whatson/tunnel-trip.htm)

> Travel by boat through Islington tunnel on the Regent's Canal, opened
>   in 1820, and around three quarters of a mile in length. When it first
>   opened boats had to be pushed through by a process of "legging" where
>   men lay on the boat and pushed against the walls with their legs. Our
>   trips are more easily achieved on board one of London's community
>   narrowboats. We use the historic converted working narrowboat
>   Tarporley, for many of these boat trips. A guide from the museum
>   offers you a commentary on the history of the tunnel as you cruise
>   through it.

**Prices and dates**

> Prices are £8.30 adult, £6.00 children, including admission to the
>   museum. The boat trip is not offered on its own without museum
>   admission. Please visit the museum before the boat departs if
>   travelling on the 1500 or 1600 trips.
>
> Dates for 2014 are the second and fourth Sundays of May to September,
>   and 2nd Sunday of October.
>       May 11th and 25th
>       June 8th and 22nd
>       July 13th and 27th
>       August 10th and 24th
>       September 14th and 28th 
>       October 12th
>
> Departure times from the museum:
>
> ```
> 1100
> 1200
> 1400
> 1500
> 1600 (no re-entry to museum after this trip, which will return to York Way, close to King's Cross station, or to the museum without
> ```
>
> access to the building)

More information is available on their website, and I assure you if you want a tour longer than the hour or so they offer, they'll be able to point you in the direction of other companies. Similarly, if you wanted to hire one yourself for a couple of days.

Comment: Great answer. I've been to the Canal Museum and it's small but very interesting. They also have a huge 'well' where blocks of ice from Norway were stored. These were cut up and distributed to keep food cool in the days before refrigeration.